# Regx for string 2 digits and 10 alphabets irrespective of their position in string

Tags: regex

Regular expression in java for a string which can contain 2 digits & 10 alphabets irrespective of their position in String

Examples of string are:

```
1abcdefghij2
12abcdefghij
abcdefghij12
abcdefg1hij2
ab12cdefghij
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){10}).*\d.*\d`

Answer (score 1):

I think the regex you are looking for is like this.

**Regex:** `^(?=\D*\d\D*\d\D*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=\D*\d\D*\d\D*$)` checks for presence of 2 digits.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}` makes sure that the total length is 12.
- Since presence of 2 digits is already checked obviously there will be 10 alphabets.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW4cV1/3)**</kbd>

**Edit #1:** Edited regex on [Sebastian Proske's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836111/sebastian-proske) advice from

`^(?=.*\d.*\d)[a-z0-9]{12}$` to `^(?=\D*\d\D*\d\D*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$`

Comment: It matches `123azdsqefds`

Comment: It matches for more then 2 digit also. It should not accept exact 2 digits & exact 10 characters

Comment: Yes ! I noticed that. Am improving upon it.

Comment: `(?=\D*\d\D*\d\D*$)` might be, what you are searching for

Comment: @SebastianProske: Yes I tried that earlier with `[^\d]` but wasn't working. with `\D` it's working fine. Thanks mate !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

`[12a-j]+` for strings not limited by length and `[12a-j]{12}` for string exactly 12 characters long.

You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/uZ9wN4/1).